# Flutter Pod Install error - "[!] Oh no, an error occurred."

Tags: ios, flutter, installation, cocoapods

## What happened?

When I wanted to run the code below, I get an error.

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
arch -x86_64 pod install //I have a m1 pro MacBook, so i have to add "arch -x86_64"
```

#### Why I needed to run this.

I am in the process of uploading an app to the Apple AppStore, but there was a problem in the build. I needed to remove Firebase Storage, which i am not using anyway. After doing this, i often have to run the code above. So I did.

#### What I have tried, but did not work.

```
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos
rm -rf master
pod setup
```

and

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod setup
```

this gave 'permission denied' for 'rm' on everything in 'trunk'

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/

pod install
```

#### Any help would be appreciated.

## The terminal error output

```
Analyzing dependencies
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Project at /Users/frederikalexanderbehrens/Documents/Wordoss/Runner.xcodeproj does not exist. Please check paths or incorporate Crashlytics upload symbols manually.
firebase_crashlytics: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '10.3.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
Downloading dependencies
Installing AppAuth (1.6.0)
```

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

#### Command

```
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/bin/pod install
```

#### Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.12.0
        Ruby : ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x86_64-darwin22]
    RubyGems : 3.4.10
        Host : macOS 13.1 (22C65)
       Xcode : 14.2 (14C18)
         Git : git version 2.37.3
Ruby lib dir : /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/3.2.2/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

#### Podfile

```rb
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '11.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

#### Error

```
Errno::EACCES - Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /Users/frederikalexanderbehrens/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/VERSION
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:171:in `initialize'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:171:in `open'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:171:in `open'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:171:in `ensure_matching_version'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader/cache.rb:22:in `initialize'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:41:in `new'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/downloader.rb:41:in `download'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_downloader.rb:69:in `download!'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:117:in `download_source'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/pod_source_installer.rb:67:in `install!'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:621:in `install_source_of_pod'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:539:in `block (2 levels) in install_pod_sources'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:86:in `titled_section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:538:in `block in install_pod_sources'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:535:in `each'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:535:in `install_pod_sources'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:258:in `block in download_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:257:in `download_dependencies'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:163:in `install!'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.12.0/libexec/bin/pod:25:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=Permission+denied+%40+rb_sysopen+-+%2FUsers%2Ffrederikalexanderbehrens%2FLibrary%2FCaches%2FCocoaPods%2FPods%2FVERSION&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Found no similar issues. To create a new issue, please visit:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/issues/new

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `12.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
frederikalexanderbehrens@Wordoss ios %

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases this will help:

1. delete Podfile.lock
2. run `pod update`
3. if it still doesn't work, run `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi` then `arch -x86_64 pod install` and retry step 2.

Step 3. resolve XCode or Flutter update issues, also on Mac M1/M2 Chips

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

## How I ended up making it work

After looking up many different solutions and spending hours, the problem was that so many of my files were "read-only". So pod install could not work.

#### If you have this problem, try this: (Mac only)

1. Enter your Flutter SDK folder.
2. In tool bar click File then get info.
3. Under "Sharing & Permissions", mark your user with "read & write".
4. In the same window, unlock the lock in the bottom right.
5. Click the dropdown menu below it, and say "apply to enclosed items".

You might have to repeat for different folders. I had to do it for my ios folder too.